# app crashing, need help understanding what the problem is

Tags: java, android

Error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.murach.splash/com.wickham.android.splash.Splash}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
at com.wickham.android.splash.Splash.onCreate(Splash.java:47)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Splash Activity

```
package com.wickham.android.splash;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;



public class Splash extends Activity {
    int i;

    String getURL = "http://www.your-server.com/english-proper-names.txt";
    String ip204 =  "http://www.your-server.com/return204.php";

    public static int ConnectTimeout = 10000;
    public static int ReadTimeout = 10000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        this.setContentView(R.layout.splash);
47
48      // Setup the ActionBar and the Spinner in the ActionBar
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setSubtitle("Practical Android");
        getActionBar().setTitle("Splash");

        if (haveNetworkConnection()) {
            new HttpDownload().execute();
        }
        else {
            noConnection();
        }
    }

    private boolean haveNetworkConnection() {
        boolean HaveConnectedWifi = false;
        boolean HaveConnectedMobile = false;

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
        for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo)
        {
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    HaveConnectedWifi = true;
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    HaveConnectedMobile = true;
        }
        return HaveConnectedWifi || HaveConnectedMobile;
    }

    public class HttpDownload extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
            publishProgress("Connecting","0");
            String fromServer = "";
            int BUFFER_SIZE = 2000;
            float fsize = 890000;
            InputStream in = null;
            try {
                // Check for reachability
                URL url = new URL(ip204);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setConnectTimeout(ConnectTimeout);
                conn.setReadTimeout(ReadTimeout);
                conn.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
                in = conn.getInputStream();
                int status = conn.getResponseCode();
                in.close();
                conn.disconnect();
                if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NO_CONTENT) {
                    // Server is reachabile, so initiate the download
                    publishProgress("Connecting:", "0");
                    in = OpenHttpConnection(getURL);
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
                    int charRead;
                    char[] inputBuffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
                    while ((charRead = isr.read(inputBuffer))>0) {
                        //---convert the chars to a String---
                        String readString = String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer, 0, charRead);
                        fromServer += readString;
                        inputBuffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
                        //---update the progress
                        float ratio = (fromServer.length() / fsize) * 100;
                        int num = (int) ratio;
                        publishProgress("Connecting: " + String.valueOf(num) + "%", String.valueOf(num));
                    }
                    in.close();
                } else {
                    publishProgress("Not Reachable", "0");
                    failedReach();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                failedDownload();
            }
            publishProgress("Completed","100");
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this, Main.class));
            finish();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... item) {
            TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
            txt.setText(item[0]);
            ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progBar);
            int num = Integer.parseInt(item[1]);
            progressBar.setProgress(num);
        }
    }

    public void noConnection() {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Splash.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Connection");
        alertDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning);
        alertDialog.setMessage("Data connection not available. Please restart.");
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialog.setButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            } });
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    public void failedReach() {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Splash.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Connection");
        alertDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning);
        alertDialog.setMessage("Connection available, but server could not be reached. Please restart.");
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialog.setButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            } });
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    public void failedDownload() {

        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Splash.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Connection");
        alertDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning);
        alertDialog.setMessage("Connection available, but downloading failed. Please restart.");
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialog.setButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            } });
        alertDialog.show();

    }

    public static InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = null;
        int response = -1;

        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection)) throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");

        try{
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();

            response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
            if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                in = httpConn.getInputStream();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IOException("Error connecting");
        }
        return in;
    }
}
```

Splash Line 47 as noted above does not have any code written in it, so i'm unsure as to why it is bringing an error.

Comment: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use `getSupportActionBar()` method, if you didn't make changes regarding ActionBar(eg.Theme to change No Action Bar).

The reason why you should use `getSupportActionBar() method` is due to what `MainActivity inherits from, which is AppCompatActivity.`

if you dive deep into source code, `getActionBar() method derives from Activity.class` whereas `getSupportActionBar() method derives from AppCompatActivity, which MainActivity inherits from.`

if you take a look at `AppCompatActivity class`, it has delegate class: `AppCompatDelegate(abstract)` and this `AppCompatDelegate.class is implemented by AppCompatDelegateImpl.class, and this is where you get action bar in your case.`

Both Activity.class and AppCompatDelegateImpl.class have mActionBar as member variable, but since your MainActivity.class inherits AppCompatActivity.class, you need to call getSupportActionBar() method to retrieve the value you want.

p.s. if you open `AppCompatDelagateImpl.class` and find `getSupportActionBar()` ,
it has commented with

> The Action Bar should be lazily created as hasActionBar
> could change after onCreate

if you wonder how to explore, I marked a breakpoint to the line where it retrieves actionbar and kept pressing F5(on window) to know how it returns action bar.